# How to Handle Popup Window in Spring?

Tags: java, jquery, spring

In my Spring Application have Display some Existing Users in Database In Jsp

```
<a id="details" href="#"class="copyright-text read_link" title="FAQs" onclick="sendForm()";>    

<label for="subject">${user.name}</label>   
</a>
```

When we Click above Hyper link one `Popup will open and show his Details`

And my Controller class i'm mapping action to hyperlink click event.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String header(SearchForm form, BindingResult result,
            Model model) throws Exception {
    -----
    -----
    model.addAttribute("SEARCH_RESULT", form);
    return "search";
}
```

So this `search.jsp` should display on above popup window.

In this Purpose i'm doing like this..

Prepare ajax form submitting , i'm writing success event so popup.

```
function ajaxFormSubmit(options) {

$.ajax({
    url : options.action,
    success : function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            $('#' + options.successElem).html(data);
        }

    },
    error : function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        apprise(textStatus +" " + errorThrown);
    }
});
}
```

But this is not working. so is this procedure correct or not ?

Other wise tell me how to Open popup window in Spring ?

Comment: What errors are you getting?

Comment: Actually call was not going to Server , popup open and show message "error Bad Request"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your code, HTTP method is specified as POST in the @RequestMapping, while GET method is used for sending the ajax request. Is this the cause of your problem?